# SSRS: Populate Checkbox Parameter with dataset, then use those results in a where condition in the query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I know what I want to accomplish, but not the steps to get me there.

DataSet2 looks about like this:

select * from TableSet2

```
ID  TheName
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

ReportParameter1 "get values from a query", with DataSet2, ValueField is TableSet2."ID", and Label Field is TableSet2."TheName".

The following query works as intended:

```
select * from TableSet1
where TableSet1.Property = @ReportParameter1
```

Then when I write a query for DataSet1, something the following, I get error messages:

```
select * from TableSet1
where TableSet1.Property in @ReportParameter1
```

Can anyone help me get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a multi-valued parameter? If yes, then use the below code:

```
select * from TableSet1
where TableSet1.Property in (@ReportParameter1)
```

If it is a single-valued parameter, then your code should look like this:

```
select * from TableSet1
where TableSet1.Property = @ReportParameter1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx), you need parentheses around your parameter or values:

```
select * from TableSet1
where TableSet1.Property in (@ReportParameter1)
```